# The phrase "Spirits abroad"

Tags: ambiguity

In the [abroad entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abroad) of The Oxford Living Dictionaries, there are a handful of examples containing the word *spirit* (Examples are rearranged by me):

1. [T]here is a new buccaneering **spirit** abroad.
2. First, there may be an entrepreneurial **spirit** increasingly abroad in Sweden and its cultural industries that has led to a wave of start-ups.
3. A **spirit** of enquiry is abroad among the Chinese, and there is a class of students, by no means small in number, who receive with avidity instruction on scientific matters from the West.
4. After all the bitterness in the game over the past few years, there seemed something of a new **spirit** abroad, to which the persona of Tony Gilbert, the Borders' Kiwi coach, has contributed.
5. When traditional people speak of **‘spirits’** that are abroad, they tend to refer to presence such as the wind, or the creative force of a word.

---

1. In short, at the top of the new century he caught a new **spirit** abroad.
2. The OED gives, ‘When a nation is in the throes of revolution, wild **spirits** are abroad in the storm.’
3. In our three weeks in Cornwall, Wales and Ireland, we saw amazing sites and felt remarkable **spirits** abroad in the land.

As for the first group of examples I can identify the meaning of the word *spirit* with the second meaning in [spirit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spirit):

> **2** *[in singular]* The prevailing or typical quality, mood, or attitude of a person, group, or period of time.

What about last three examples? Do they refer to a ghost or an ethos?

Comment: In this sense "abroad" means "spread widely".

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about the word _spirit_.

Comment: And what does a dictionary tell you??

Comment: As I mention in the last paragraph,  I looked it up in a dictionary, but the meaning remained ambiguous for me between ghost and ethos.

Comment: depending on your level and grasp of English ... this can be s/w difficult.

Comment: 'Spirit' here is ethos {see [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ethos)}, prevailing mood / attitude in the country etc, though it can also be used in this sense  for smaller gatherings / notional groups or even individuals.  'Abroad' emphasises the fact that it is widespread.

Comment: Consider the German word Zeitgeist, "spirit of the age", which has been adopted into English.  "Zeit" is "time" or "tide" (not the oceanic sort) and "Geist" is "ghost" or "spirit", so that if the word had been constructed in English the way it was in German, we would say "tideghost".  It seems to me that the word "spirit" in the first four examples at the beginning of this discussion would be well represented by Zeitgeist, but I don't recommend changing the wording: "spirit" is better in each of the four examples.

Comment: *Spirits abroad* is idiomatic and shouldn't be taken literally. Idioms are always figurative, which perhaps explains the confusion. "An idiom is an expression that conveys something different from its literal meaning, and that cannot be guessed from the meanings of its individual words." Figures of speech are likewise non-literal. http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Idioms-metaphors-similes-and-hyperbole

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would you please explain the first sentence: "In short, at the top of the new century he caught a new spirit abroad." In particular, how _he_ (one single person) caught a new spirit _widespreadly_? Do we speak about an exorcist?

Comment: I'd like more context for the "...he caught a new spirit abroad," but I'd take it to mean that someone ("he") had traveled abroad and had been invigorated/enlightened/encouraged by what he encountered.

Comment: 'Caught' here is almost certainly 'discerned that there was'. As in "I didn't quite catch that." But there's insufficient context given by ODO in this example to be sure.

Comment: I'd add that  ‘When a nation is in the throes of revolution, wild spirits are abroad in the storm.’ is [almost certainly] not referencing the entities known as _evil spirits_, but is deliberately conflating the literal (though abstract) sense (2) you mention with a metaphorical usage ('the storm' indicates this).

Comment: Your link doesn't connect to the quotations you use.

Comment: @Xanne The meaning of _spirit_, though it's added later to my post by some nice editor, is apparently there. As for examples, they cannot be linked individually. Please click on "More example sentences" buttons and find the quotations using your browser's search facility.

Answer (score -1):

**spirit(s)**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spirit)

> a. A force or principle believed to animate living beings. b. A force
>   or principle believed to animate humans and often to endure after
>   departing from the body of a person at death; the soul.
>   2. Spirit The Holy Spirit.
>   3. A supernatural being, as: a. An angel or demon. b. A being inhabiting or embodying a particular place, object, or natural
>   phenomenon. c. A fairy or sprite.

**abroad**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/abroad)

> 4. In circulation; at large.
> 5. Covering a large area; widely

Spirits Abroad:  any and/or all spirits, here and/or elsewhere.

As in:

> At the top of the new century he found a new *force* at large in the
>   land etc ...
>
> When a nation is in the throes of revolution, wild *ideas* are abroad
>   in the storm.
>
> In our three weeks in Cornwall, Wales and Ireland, we saw amazing
>   sites and 'felt' the remarkable historical souls abroad in the land.

Comment: "In short, at the top of the new century he caught a new spirit abroad." How he could catch a new spirit _here and everywhere_? Was he an exorcist? I can't make sense of this sentence.

Comment: @Kaveh "Caught" here does not mean captured; it means _sensed_ or _perceived_.  "Abroad" may mean "at large" or it may mean _overseas_, e.g., an Englishman talking about a change of spirit (view, attitude toward life) in Europe.

Answer (score -2):

According to *English Idioms*, by James Main Dixon, M.A., F.R.S.E. (Professor of English Literature in the Imperial University of Japan), ca. 1902:

> [Abroad. **ALL ABROAD** (a) *in a state of mental perplexity*.](https://ia800209.us.archive.org/24/items/englishidioms00dixouoft/englishidioms00dixouoft_djvu.txt) [Familiar or informal usage]:
>
> The female boarder in black attire looked so puzzled, and, in fact, all *abroad* (perplexed), after the delivery of this "counter" of mine, that I left her to recover her wits, and went on with the conversation. HOLMES.
>
> He is such a poor, cracked, crazy creature, with his mind all *abroad*. A. TROLLOPS.
>
> (6) having the senses confused; without complete control of one's organism [Familiar or informal usage]
>
> At the twelfth round the latter champion was all *abroad*, as the saying is, and had lost all presence of mind and power of attack or defence. THACKERAY.

Meanwhile, [**spirits**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spirit) in this context could mean emotions, according to *Oxford Living Dictionaries*:

> A person's mood or attitude.

In conclusion, while you have provided many different examples of usage for the idiom, *spirits abroad*, most of them refer to a general sense of emotions being either completely out of control or at least all over the place, or *unbridled*.